# Concatenate string with object in Powershell

Tags: powershell, concatenation

Currently I want to get a list of active user on Windows 10 using Powershell.
After some searching I found this helps:

```
Get-LocalUser | Where-Object -Property Enabled -eq True
```

And here is the output:

```
Name       Enabled Description
----       ------- -----------
User_1     True               
User_2     True
```

I just want to concatenate strings to a list of values of Name column from above, which will be like below:

```
Active user(s): User_1, User_2
```

Do you have any idea how I can do that? I'm just a non-tech guy trying to learn some useful command so forgive me if this is a basic to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
# Retrieve the name values
$Users = Get-LocalUser |
    Where-Object Enabled -eq True | Select-Object -Expand Name
# Create the output string
"Active user(s): {0}" -f ($Users -join ', ')
```

Using `-Expand` (or `-ExpandProperty`) from [Select-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7), the target property's value is returned rather than the object that contains the property.

`-f` is the string [format operator](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-f-operator.html). It uses substitution for the `{position}` syntax. The `-join` operator creates a string from a list with `,`  as the delimiter.

Comment: So can I count the number of active user? Just for curious.

Comment: `$users.count` for the count

Comment: It works like a charm XD Really appreciate your help.